# Import tree of object in solr from mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, solr

I have tha follow structure in mongodb:

```
{
    "status": "1",
    "instancia": "1",
    "infoAdicionais": {
        "partes": [{
            "id": "123"
        }]
    }
}
```

At *schema.xml* in solr, how I declare field **infoAdicionais**?
I have tried:

```
<field name="infoAdicionais" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" docValues="true" />
```

but not works.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you planning to search that? When you get your 10 results on a page, what is one of those results? That should be your Solr document in most cases.

Solr is not a database designed to preserve data structure. Solr wants to you modify, combine, split and denormalize data structures to allow you to find information fast.

If you are not searching **partes** by ID, you may not even need to preserve it. If you do it, what do you expect to get back? Do you map multiple ids into the same object or different ones? These are the questions for you to answer first.

As to specifically for the nested structures support, Solr [does supports parent and child documents](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Data+with+Index+Handlers#UploadingDatawithIndexHandlers-NestedChildDocuments), but the schema is a combined superset of fields from one and from another.